# How to add subdomain on another ec2 instance AWS in Cloudflare?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subdomain, cloudflare

I am hosting my main site on ec2 let’s say instance1, my domain is from go daddy so i put cloudflare nameserver on go daddy. now i have another installation on ec2 let’s say instance 2 and it is a subdomain. instance 1 and 2 have different IP’s how can i point my subdomain to instance 2?
which records should i change in AWS and in cloudflare to achieve this?

My Cloudflare DNS added in Godaddy

```
NS  lisa.ns.cloudflare.com
NS  sid.ns.cloudflare.com
```

DNS setting in Cloudflare account

```
 Type           Name           Value                                   TTL        
    A        mydomainname.com     points to 13.232.XXX.XXX          Automatic       
    CNAME    test                 is an alias of mydomainname.com    Automatic      
    CNAME    www                  is an alias of mydomainname.com    Automatic      
    TXT      mydomainname.com     ca3-b78797cee2b346558bf7a891ff5bd5daXX Automatic
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change any records in AWS, since you using Cloudflare as your DNS service.
 Cloudflare gives you ability to modify DNS zone settings, add A, CNAME and other records.

Just obtain public IP for instance-2 from AWS console, login to Cloudflare, open you domain DNS zone editor and add `A` record with name of your subdomain pointing to IP of a second instance.

UPDATE:
in your cloudflare configuration it should look like:

```
Type           Name           Value                                   TTL        
    A        mydomainname.com     points to 13.232.XXX.XXX          Automatic
    A        subdomain            points to 123.123.123.123          Automatic       
    CNAME    test                 is an alias of mydomainname.com    Automatic      
    CNAME    www                  is an alias of mydomainname.com    Automatic      
    TXT      mydomainname.com     ca3-b78797cee2b346558bf7a891ff5bd5daXX Automatic
```

Comment: already tried add `A` record with my sub domain with IP address but not pointing my Insistence, still showing 522 error

Comment: First, you can check with nslookup if your DNS subname resolving to correct ip. 
After, you need to investigate 522 error - most likely the issue is your security group or instance firewall not allowing incoming traffic. What do you see if you enter your IP directly into browser address string?

Comment: as you mentioned I tried to do above changes I getting error like `A CNAME already exists with that host. (Code: 81054)` for more check this link https://prnt.sc/mbdpwx

Comment: yes, you need to remove existing CNAME record for `test` first

Comment: I removed `CNAME` record added new `test` `A` record along with my EC2 IP address, but I checked in DNS lookup my sub domain still pointing cloudflare IP address

Comment: This is because you have cloudflare proxy enabled (orange cloud icon). Just click on it and set to disable if you want DNS to resolve into your ip address. However, your site should be already accessible via cloudflare proxy service.

Comment: ok thanks for the update, I need SSL from provided cloudflare for my sub domain as well as, it is possible

Comment: If your ssl is wildcard it will cover all subdomains, otherwise you need to get another certificate for this subdomain. Cloudflare can provide you a free certificate as long as you using their service.

Comment: Also make sure that on cloudflare, under crypto you are having the correct type of ssl connection. If your ec2 instance does not support https connections then enable `flexible ssl `so cloudflare can communicate to your instance through http